# Make a semi oval button in android xml

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

I am new in GUI field and i am struggling to create a GUI button for my app. I am trying to mimic the button like attached image. Please help me.

### [image: Image of GUI]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put 3 Textview in linearLayout(Horization) and set Custom style on each textview.

create 3 drawable for custom style on textview

**random_textview.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
        <solid android:color="#8D7AA5"/> 
        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
    </shape>
```

**friend_textview.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
        <solid android:color="#7096BD"/> 
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"/>
    </shape>
```

**ok_textview.xml**

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <solid android:color="#808080"/> 
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it made my night, i can sleep in peace. Just a little edit in the ok_textview.xml and everything worked fine.

Comment: Most Welcome..Happy Coding :D